# Image tag in FXML (JavaFX), how to set size using css?

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I'm learning to use CSS with FXML and I'm having trouble setting the size of an Image. I have four images, and I want them all to be the same size. But I can't get the CSS to work. My FXML is as follows.

```xml
<HBox styleClass="sidebar-item" >
    <ImageView styleClass="icon" preserveRatio="true">
        <Image url="@assets/settings.png" />
    </ImageView>
    <Label text="%settings" />
</HBox>
```

The following is my CSS for the icon class.

```css
.icon {
    -fx-pref-height: 20px;
    -fx-pref-width: 20px;
    -fx-max-width: 20px;
    -fx-max-height: 20px;
    -fx-min-width: 20px;
    -fx-min-height: 20px;
}
```

Nothing actually happens. The size remains the same. If however, I add requestedHeight="20" and requestedWidth="20" on in the ImageView xml tag, the image resizes.

```xml
<HBox styleClass="sidebar-item" >
    <ImageView styleClass="icon" preserveRatio="true">
        <Image url="@assets/settings.png" requestedHeight="20" requestedWidth="20"/>
    </ImageView>
    <Label text="%settings" />
</HBox>
```

Is it not possible to achieve the same using css? I can't find any CSS tags relating to requestedWidth, and I'm also not allowed to set a CSS class on the Image tag. Only the ImageView tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only styleable property of `ImageView`, other than those inherited from `Node`, is the `image` property (though it's a little more complicated than that internally). This means you can't set properties such as `fitWidth` via CSS. You also can't affect the `Image` itself via CSS as it's not even `Styleable`; on top of that, the requested width/height values are used during construction and don't change over time. I'm afraid, outside of writing a wrapper class, you'll have to keep using FXML or Java to configure the size of the image.

Comment: Well, at least I know not to waste any more time on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
-fx-scale-x: 1; <!-- Range 1 = 100%>

-fx-scale-y: 0; <!-- Range 0 = 0%>
```

ImageView has all Node properties. https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node

Comment: Using an Imageview text inside a button with text may experience unwanted results.